# jQuery - Select second word and warp the text

Tags: jquery

I have a menu list like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="but"><a href="#">ONE WORD<small>Other words here</small></a></li>
<li class="but"><a href="#">ONE WORD<small>Other words here</small></a></li>
<li class="but"><a href="#">ONE WORD<small>Other words here</small></a></li>
<li class="but"><a href="#">ONE WORD<small>Other words here</small></a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I automatically select the second word from li.but and warp it into a span like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="but"><a href="#">ONE <span>WORD<span><small>Other words here</small></a></li>
<li class="but"><a href="#">ONE <span>WORD<span><small>Other words here</small></a></li>
<li class="but"><a href="#">ONE <span>WORD<span><small>Other words here</small></a></li>
<li class="but"><a href="#">ONE <span>WORD<span><small>Other words here</small></a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('li.but > a').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/\s(.*?)\s/, ' <span>$1</span> ');
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/6dkAy/3/

Comment: It works but also adds an extra "small" tag inside "span". Select output and view selection source.

Comment: I was trying to figure out a regex to do this, unfortunately this method (and mine, w/your fix) only works if there's a space after the `<small>` tag.

Comment: First I thought regex too but after a few trial and failure I choosed the longest but the safest method.

Comment: @kara I've updated my demo. It's OK now. I expect one space character (at least) between the second word and the `<small>` tag.

Comment: @Matt You mean before? There has to be a space before the `<small>` tag.

Comment: I tried my hand at the regex version and got it working with no changes to the markup needed. Check it out.

Comment: @kara I initially placed the space character on the wrong place. It has to be between the second word and the `<small>` tag. Good that you noticed this `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
$('ul > li.but > a').html(function (i, oldHtml)
{
    return oldHtml.replace(/(\s)(\w+)/, '$1<span>$2</span>');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/ptUuS/

Comment: `html()` instead of `text()`. Live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/6dkAy/2/

Comment: I had to ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845143/javascript-regular-expression-with-capturing-parentheses) to figure this out. `:)`

Comment: Btw, this would be ok too: `replace(/\s(\w+)/, ' <span>$1</span>')`.

Comment: @Šime yes, I figured that part out already, though it took a little while (then I realized, _duh_, exactly what BoltClock's answer said). Re: your other comment, I'd rather play it safe, since `\s` matches a whole lot more than just spaces. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#endnote_equivalent_s

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
$('.but a').each(function() {
   var $a = $(this);
   var $small = $a.find('small');
   var smallText = $small.html();
   $small.remove();
   var arr = $a.html().split(' ');
   arr[1] = ['<span>', arr[1], '</span>'].join('');
   $a.html(arr.join(' ')).append(['<small>', smallText, '</small>'].join(''));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/rvxB3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
$("ul > li > a").each(function(index, el) {

   var sec = $(this).html().split(" ");
   sec = sec[1].split("<")[0];
   var total = "<span>" + sec + "</span>";

   var html = $("ul > li > a").html();
   html = html.replace(sec, total);
   $(this).html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a code for wrapping the second word in a span with a class. Maybe you can adopt it. do something like this;

`$('.list-item a').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text().split(' ');
    if(text.length < 2)
        return;
    text[1] = '<span class="color-red">'+text[1]+'</span>';
    $(this).html( text.join(' ') );
});`