# JavaScript regular expression with capturing parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this paragraph:

```
<p>FIRST SECOND THIRD</p>
```

and I want to wrap the second word in a SPAN like so:

```
<p>FIRST <span>SECOND</span> THIRD</p>
```

If I do this:

```
text.replace(/\s(\w+)\s/, '<span>$1</span>');
```

the space characters before and after the word disappear. Why? What am I doing wrong? I thought `/\s(\w+)\s/` captures the word but not the spaces.

**See here:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/TpTzV/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaces are stripped away because they're part of the entire match. The capture is what it *remembers* to substitute back into the replacement string via backreferences.

If JavaScript supported both lookahead and lookbehind assertions you could do this:

```
text.replace(/(?<\s)(\w+)(?=\s)/, '<span>$1</span>');
```

But it doesn't, so you can try capturing the spaces (separately from the word you're wrapping) and putting them back in instead:

```
text.replace(/(\s)(\w+)(\s)/, '$1<span>$2</span>$3');
```

Comment: @Bolt So `$1` represents the entire match and not the first capturing parentheses?

Comment: `$1` represents the first capture. The entire match is denoted by [`$&`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688730/what-does-in-str-replacespecials-mean/4688753#4688753).

Comment: @Bolt But the entire match is going to be replaced with the string, not just the first capture. That's where I got it wrong...

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yup, that's why you capture the spaces along with the word and put them all back in.

Comment: The lookahead/behind regex would work because the matches wouldn't be "consumed" -- so won't be a part of the match. It's a shame Javascript doesn't support these kind of regexes, they are useful in many occasions.

Answer (score 1):

$1 will be the part captured by the bit you have wrapped in parentheses, which is \w+, which will consist of word characters and not spaces.  If you want to capture the spaces too, do this:

```
/(\s\w+\s)/
```

Comment: That'd result in `<span> SECOND </span>`, with the spaces within the tags.

Comment: That's what I thought you wanted, for whatever reason.  If you want the spaces outside the <span> tags, then you need either three different captures (one for each space and one for the word, which appears to be the answer you've accepted) or you need to insert the spaces in your replace like this:  text.replace(/\s(\w+)\s/, ' <span>$1</span> ');    Note that that last one will replace whatever whitespace character is on either side of the word with a space.  But if that doesn't matter to you, then that will do it.

Comment: Note that the original comment to your answer is not from me `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces disapear because is not grouped.

Try with:

```
replace(/(\s\w+\s)/
```

Spaces (`\s`) inside the grouping.